# Tor on guest account

Tags: mac

Tor works fine for me as a normal user. However, to get utmost privacy I want to use Tor from the Mac standard guest account. This is denied with "The program Torbrowser cannot be started on this computer" (translated from the German message). Right-click-open no difference. MacOS-10.14.3 up to date. Any clue anybody ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware of, Tor **must** be ran with higher level of permission (ex, admin and especially not guest) rights. There is no way around that

If you really want to, you should be able to run Tor as admin from the guest account (but that would be very much redundant)

Comment: I checked by generating a normal test account. Same problem, Tor does not ignite. Why would Tor need admin privileges !?

Comment: The fact that in creates a virtual network connection and such.

Comment: I can make a VPN connection from a guest user account using Cisco VPN sans problem.

Comment: @falkho that is not Tor, so really is invalid. Tor needs admin rights, simply put. Have you tried from a standard user (not guest or admin) account?

Comment: See my message 2 days ago: "I checked by generating a normal test account. Same problem, Tor does not ignite." So yes, I tried from a standard user account. I also do not see the logic in "Tor needs admin rights, have you tried from a non-admin account". Apparently Tor requires admin rights for spurious reasons, NOT because of VPN. Is there nobody who knows the reason?

Comment: @falkho don't snap at me. I didn't design tor

Comment: @falkho tor does not use VPN. Network overlay and VPN are different